# I am trying to build a data dictionary for the ticker symbol 'AAPL' However i run into this error msg HTTPError: HTTP Error 400:

Tags: api, repository, clone

This is the function
apple_dict=f.build_dict('AAPL')

This is the Main Script

def profile_data_(self,symbol):
"""
Pulls the metrics data from the API for the given ticker symbol

```
    Parameters
    ----------
    symbol : A ticker symbol (str) e.g. 'MSFT','FB','AAPL', or 'TWTR'

    Returns
    -------
    None. Updates the self.profile with the data. 
    """        
    if not self.key_registered:
        print("API key not registered yet.")
        return None
    
    url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/"+'?apikey='+self.key
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    self.profile = json.loads(data)
    return json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Far too much code. Please reduce it to the bare minimum needed to provide a [mre] - that means not one line of code that is not necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @KenWhite https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: @SpeedoThreeSixty: Your point? I've known about those pages since they were created. I chose to offer the poster an opportunity to edit their post, as they are a very new user here.

Comment: @KenWhite The URL of "i downvoted because" does not have to always imply that you downvoted. It can simply be a tool to explain why a question should be edited, without typing how to fix it in every single comment. This is what I meant by the link - to tell you that they are still helpful to fix the question.

Comment: @SpeedoThreeSixty: Using that link requires the poster to leave this site to read the contents. Having them do so is discouraged by this site in all other cases (such as link-only answers), and I don't see any reason to do so here either.

Comment: @KenWhite Is this an better?

Comment: A [mre] means the absolute minimum code that can be copied and pasted into a code editor and executed to demonstrate the problem. It doesn't appear that you've provided sufficient code for that - you may have removed a little too much. It's much closer now, though.

Comment: @KenWhite There is a new tab feature for opening links.

Should we redirect this to chat?

Comment: @SpeedoThreeSixty: New tabs are irrelevant. It's still asking the user to go to another site for no reason. I don't see any reason to go to chat. I choose not to use the links you reference. There's nothing to discuss about that choice - it's mine to make.